# Is there any way to get the list of current users of a web app?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have deployed a script as web app (on a domain), and I want to have the list of users who are currently using the script.
My script can take several days running (using triggers).
I want to publish a new version and notify current users in order to authorize the script again.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide more information on how the app is deployed ?

Comment: @Serge The app is deployed to be executed on the account of the user accessing the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have deployed your app to run as the logged in user, each time someone accesses the script, you can fetch the user's email address and store it in a spreadsheet for the first time. You can also store a flag that the user's email has been recorded and check the flag each time the user logs in

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var res = db.query{'firstTime'};
if (!res.hasNext()) { 
   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
   /*Write this email to your spreadsheet */ 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but one of the improvements of the new version is logging the Current users in a spreadsheet. But I just want to notify people who are currently running my script that a new version is ready.

Comment: I'm not sure what new version you are referring to. Can you please shed more light on it